# Against the context of John Chapter One, are the three records of John the Baptist's words, concerning Jesus, a proof of Jesus' pre-existence?

Tags: exegesis, life-of-jesus, trinity, gospel-of-john

Three times, the apostle John records the witness of John the Baptist regarding Jesus being 'after' John yet 'before' John and 'first' - in 1:15, 1:27 and 1:30.

> John bore witness of Him, and cried out, saying, This was He of whom I said, He who comes after me, has a higher rank than I, for He existed before me. - John 1:15

> He it is, who coming after me is preferred before me, whose shoe's latchet I am not worthy to unloose. [John 1:27 KJV]

> This is He on behalf of whom I said, After me comes a Man who has a higher rank than I, for He existed before me. - John 1:30

Do Trinitarians view this as proof of the pre-existence of Jesus Christ and do they see more in this regarding the relevant ministeries of John and Jesus ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133004/discussion-on-question-by-mr-bond-is-there-a-connection-between-what-the-apostl).

Comment: @Kris The system flagged these comments as too many and I agree that they are numerous now, so they are diverted to chat. **Please use chat to continue this conversation.** Pax.

Comment: @KenGraham I have edited and scoped the question but deliberately not attempted to exclude the single existing answer.

Comment: @NigelJ Looks good. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, these three texts are evidence of the pre-existence of the One they describe and yes they express more of the manner of his coming and of the purpose of his coming.

The full proof was when he rose from the dead : only then is he declared (publicly) to be the Son of God. For, note, that John’s gospel account was  not published until late in the first century, after Jesus was already risen and ascended.

---

- First Section - The Structure of the Chapter
- Second Section - The Witness of John
- Third Section - The Conclusion

---

**First Section - The Structure of the Chapter relative to the question**

In John 1:1-4 are two outstanding statements and I am quoting the Englishman’s Greek New Testament translation (1870 from the Stephens text of 1550) :

- John1:1  God was the Word
- John 1:14    The Word became flesh

Having made these two remarkable utterances, the Apostle John repeats the witness of John the Baptist three times :-

1. John 1:15 - The Comprehensive Statement (regarding two individuals)
2. John 1:27 - The Quantifying of the Comparative Precedence of the two
3. John 1:30 - The Qualifying of the Manner of Coming of the First Precedent

Then the Apostle reports Jesus coming to John - 1:29. Remarkably, this is the first time that the Coming One has been named. He is not, yet, identified. That happens next . . . . .  when, finally, the Apostle reports the conclusion, as stated by John the Baptist :

> I have seen and have borne witness that this is the Son of God. [John 1:34 EGNT.]

---

To reiterate : God was the Word ; the Word became flesh ; this one is named ; this one is identified.

---

**Second Section - The Witness of John the Baptist**

I am quoting the Englishman’s Greek New Testament literal renderings of the three texts and I have made it even more literal by stating the actual translation of the three simple words (‘after‘, ‘before’ and ‘first‘) which many feel they have to ‘interpret‘ and which I feel no need to do so :-

- John 1:15 who after me comes, before of me he has, for first of me he was
- John 1:27 who after me comes, who before of me has, of whom I am not worthy that I should loose of him the thong of the sandal
- John 1:30 after me comes *aner*, who before of me has, for first of me he was

[See footnote (regarding Baxter’s Analytical Greek Lexicon, 1870) for the translation of the very basic language used by John.]

**1. The Comprehensive Statement.**

The simple words on the page state exactly what they appear to state - that although Jesus came after John regarding his birth and regarding his appearing to Israel, ‘before of me he has’ for the reason, and the only reason, that ‘before me he was’.

There can be no attempt to manipulate these words to mean some other kind of precedence or another manner of importance or a different kind of rank. The words simply do not bear that meaning.

Jesus possessed a ‘beforeness’ for the simple reason that he existed prior to John’s existence.

This statement is a kind of heading and is, twice, enlarged further . . . . . .

**2. The Quantifying of the Comparative Precedence**

John the Baptist witnesses that one comes after him who is actually before because he was before.

He then states that he is not worthy to loose the sandal of him, which is a reference to redemption (see Ruth and the man with one shoe) and which makes it clear that John is not able to restrict Jesus’ progress. This we see later when ‘John stood … and Jesus walked’, 1:35 and 36, and the disciples must needs leave John and follow Jesus.

Jesus incorporates John’s ministry (“Repent for the kingdom of heaven is at hand” Matthew 3:2, of John, and Matthew 4:17, of Jesus) but goes further : even as the baptism of John is limited and the baptism of the apostles of Jesus is comprehensive, Acts 18:25.

Thus John clearly indicates his own inferior position to the coming one. This one, who, though he came after, was before. Nor does this word ‘before’ denote a higher position, the word only means ‘prior in time’. The word is never used in scripture to denote a superior position or a more superlative condition. It only ever expresses that something happens before another.

**3. The Qualifying of the Manner of Coming of the First Precedent**

Only three times in scripture is the word *aner* used of Jesus - John 1:30, of his identified coming and his precedence over John the Baptist ; Acts 17:31, of his being identified as the Judge of all humanity ; Ephesians 4:13, of his perfected and identified humanity (Head and Body) in fulness.

*Aner* represents an identifiable individual, a male person, who can be located. It is not *anthropos* which is the concept of humanity, generally. I deal with this in full detail (pp 6-29) in the book ‘The Son of man’ which can be downloaded free of charge and free of registration on my website (see profile for link). It is an important distinction and the study of that cannot be reduced to a few lines in an article.

Basically, John’s use of the word here identifies the coming one as one come in humanity. Prior to that, the Word was made flesh but no more detail was given. What kind of flesh ? Well, now we know it is *aner* flesh : an identifiable and locatable male human.

---

**The Conclusion**

There can only be one conclusion. And that conclusion is more than merely the fact of the pre-existence : the conclusion states *the manner of the pre-existence.*

If the Person who came in flesh (after John the Baptist was born) existed prior to John’s existence, then that can mean one thing and one thing only :

> John 1:34 - I have seen and have borne witness that this is the Son of God.

A prior existence cannot be human. Nor can it be an angel. Angels which left their first estate and manifested themselves on earth (having seen the daughters of men) are said to be held in everlasting chains, Jude 6. Their error is monumental.

Nor is the ‘son’ of God a creation. No Father ‘creates’ a Son. No father makes his son out of *stuff*.

A Father begets a Son, a matter of life begetting life.

And if the eternal Father ; then an eternal begetting of an eternal Son.

His is ‘glory as of only-begotten with Father, full of grace and truth’ (John 1:14EGNT).

For ‘God no-one has seen at any time : the only begotten Son who is in the bosom of the Father, he has declared [him]’ (John 1:18 EGNT).

---

This chapter plainly demonstrates solid evidence that the One who was from the beginning with God, who, indeed, was God ; and who was therefore both with God and also was God - this One came in flesh and therefore before his flesh : He was.

And His prior existence could only possibly have been as the only begotten Son of the Father.

---

**Footnote :**

Three very simple words are used by John the Baptist and recorded by John the Apostle.

‘BAGL’ is Baxter’s Analytical Greek Lexicon, 1870. There is no need whatsoever to ‘interpret’ these words and to give special meanings in the above passages to them in an attempt to ‘prove’ something. That is just improper translation.

- *Protos* - noun      (BAGL p355)  There is no dispute about this word, it means ‘first’.
- *Emprosthen* - adverb or preposition (BAGL p136) ‘Before’ in the sense of ‘in front of’. It does not mean ‘in the face of’ : that is another Greek word, *enopion*, (BAGL p143).
- *Opiso* - preposition - (BAGL p290) after or behind/at one’s back.

Answer (score 4):

"Is this proof of the pre-existence of Jesus Christ before His incarnation as a man?"

Yes.  It is a direct statement of such.

> John bare witness of him, and cried, saying, This was **he** of whom I spake, *He that cometh after me is preferred before me: for he was before me.* - John 1:15

A literal rendering of the italicized portion of this verse (without altering the Greek word order) could be as follows (taken from [Abarim Interlinear](https://www.abarim-publications.com/Interlinear-New-Testament/John/John-1-parsed.html)):

"The behind of me, coming before of me, he has become that first of me, he was"

where "behind of me" indicates temporally afterwards, "before of me" indicates temporally beforehand, and "first" indicates a superlative preference or rank (firstest).

Thus, John is saying that although he (Jesus) came temporally afterward, for he was conceived and born 6 months after John, that same "he" (Jesus) was actually temporally before John. Since it is evident that the flesh and blood humanity of Jesus had a specific starting date temporally after John it therefore must be some other aspect of Jesus which was temporally before John.

Some claim that this "coming before" indicates preference or rank but that is ruled out by the fact that preference or rank is pointed to by another word in the very same verse: "he has become that first (preferred) of me".

Others claim that what came temporally before John was an idea in the mind of God, a plan, and not a person in the proper sense.  This is ruled out by the fact that John bare witness "of him".  This point is driven home when, in verse 30, John points to the flesh and blood, walking and talking person of Jesus and says, "Him.  That's who I was talking about":

> The next day John seeth Jesus coming unto him, and saith, Behold the Lamb of God, which taketh away the sin of the world. This is he of whom I said, After me cometh a **man** which is preferred before me: for he was before me. - John 1:29-30

Having already established that John is not claiming that the flesh and blood humanity of Jesus came before him, what can be made of the statement "for he (the man who came after me) was before me"?

The word for "man" here is *aner* which highlights the individuality of a specific adult, male human person, whereas *anthropos* (one derivative) indicates humanity generally.  Interestingly, *aner* very often carries the connotation of "husband" in it's derivatives and, therefore, may have more to do with individual role than individual, physical humanness.

Regardless of how *aner* is understood John definitively points to Jesus, an individual adult, male human person and declares that:

(Temporally) after me comes a man (individual adult male human) which outranks me **because he** (that same one who was born as a man) was (temporally) before me.

The reason John gives for Jesus' preference over him is Jesus' pre-existence and his pre-existence was not flesh and blood and yet was personal.

Comment: Temporally   Webster defines.  “ of or relating to time as opposed to eternity”.  Thus you are saying that the verses indicate pre existence but not externality of Jesus.

Comment: A good try @kris ..the pope claims temporal pre-eminence...that is "superiority above ALL others"! I would not go down this pathway if I were an Arian.

Comment: @adam what are you talking about?   This has nothing to do with the Pope either

Comment: if only JW's could make connections...they have been educated in such a manner as to be incapable of joining such dots. My point is not about the pope...its about temporal pre eminence (which is a point you yourself raised!) The point is, you deny the text is about pre-existence in terms of time, which leaves you with the impossible dilemma of "superiority"...ie Jesus is the supreme God! That is an even worse outcome for your Arian doctrinal position!

Comment: @Kris I don't understand your concern.  The question asks, "Do Trinitarians view this as proof of the pre-existence of Jesus Christ?"  John, conceived 6 months before Jesus, says that Jesus was before him as regards time (temporally).

Comment: Mike the question was edited long after your answer was written

Comment: @Kris That was the question both before and after the edit.  See Nigel's comment regarding his edit of the question.

Comment: @Adam.  Jws fully embrace the pre existence of Jesus.   We believe he was created untold eons of time ago. So I was asking if mike was intimating that the words of John prove pre  existence but not necessarily eternal pre existence

Comment: @adam you should moderate your tone in comments to be less offensive

Comment: @Kris So then JW's hold that the pre-existent Jesus incarnated.

Comment: Yes mike if you can allow for the word incarnated to refer to a creature lesser than God becoming flesh we would agree that is accurate

Comment: @Kris That is what the word means, Kris.  I believe God incarnated but incarnate is not a word that has to or only applies to God.

Comment: Mike ok.  With that understanding we can agree but the word is a loaded word and even in dictionaries when used in connection to Christianity  we will find the “God became flesh” phrasing.  When angels visited in OT do you say they incarnated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133037/discussion-between-kris-and-mike-borden).